# $product->get_id() function for all products

Tags: php, wordpress, product

I've got a question.. we got a script from Enhancer for WooCommerce Subscription. This script is checking if the customer already had the product, if yes, he don't give a trial.

But all our products are the same service, just a little bit diverent points inside the packages.

So we want to check all products, not only the chosen one. Is there a way to change the get_id part to check all products?

This is the code part:

```
public static function limit_trial( $trial_length, $product ) {
    if ( $trial_length <= 0 ) {
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id() ;

    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    if ( isset( self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] ) ) {
        return self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] ? 0 : $trial_length ;
    }

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ) ;
    } else {
        $parent_product = $product ;
    }

    if ( 'no' !== self::get_product_limitation( $parent_product ) ) {
        self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] = false ;
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    if ( 'yes' !== get_post_meta( $parent_product->get_id(), '_enr_limit_trial_to_one', true ) ) {
        self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] = false ;
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id ) ;

    foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
        if ( $subscription->has_product( $product->get_id() ) && ( '' !== $subscription->get_trial_period() || 0 !== $subscription->get_time( 'trial_end' ) ) ) {
            self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] = true ;
            return 0 ;
        }
    }

    self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] = false ;
    return $trial_length ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all products using `WP_Query()` then you can iterate the loop to get the product. try the below code.

```
public static function limit_trial( $trial_length, $product ) {
    if ( $trial_length <= 0 ) {
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id() ;

    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        return $trial_length ;
    }

    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'product'
    );

    $products = new WP_Query( $params );
    
    if ( $products->have_posts() ) {  while ( $products->have_posts() ) {  $products->the_post();
        
        if ( isset( self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] ) ) {
            return self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] ? 0 : $trial_length ;
        }

        if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ) ;
        } else {
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() ) ;
        }

        if ( 'no' !== self::get_product_limitation( $parent_product ) ) {
            self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] = false ;
            return $trial_length ;
        }

        if ( 'yes' !== get_post_meta( $parent_product->get_id(), '_enr_limit_trial_to_one', true ) ) {
            self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] = false ;
            return $trial_length ;
        }

        $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id ) ;

        foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
            if ( $subscription->has_product( get_the_ID() ) && ( '' !== $subscription->get_trial_period() || 0 !== $subscription->get_time( 'trial_end' ) ) ) {
                self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] = true ;
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
        
        self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ get_the_ID() ] = false ;

    } wp_reset_postdata(); }

    return $trial_length ;
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but still not working. I already had product A and now I want to take product B, but also gives me the trial. Do I have to define the products via ID somewhere?

Comment: can you update your question with more in detail where you use this `limit_trial` function?

Comment: we are using the plugin "Enhancer for WooCommerce Subscription", this is a part of the plugin, where he checks if customer already had a trial or not. But it only checks if the product in the cart has already existed in the past. If it existed, he don't give trial, when its not existed it gives trial.

But we have 6 products, we want the script to check all 6 products, if he had one of them, he shouldn't be given a trial.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be that part of the code where he is checking, what product he had.

```
        foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
        if ( $subscription->has_product('295587','295585','295578') && ( '' !== $subscription->get_trial_period() || 0 !== $subscription->get_time( 'trial_end' ) ) ) {
            self::$onetime_trial_cache[ $user_id ][ $product->get_id() ] = true ;
            return 0 ;
        }
```

So maybe just the input with the product ID's is wrong. I really can define them by using the product IDs (I know its not dynamic, but that would be no problem). How I have to enter the products I need to check?